# How to make screenshot of OpenTok video chat?

Tags: opentok

I am trying OpenTok  (examples from GitHub [Basic-Video-Chat](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-android-sdk-samples) )
and would like to save screenshot.
Could somebody recommend me how to do it? Probably, I should somehow get Bitmap from Subscriber view?

Answer (score 0):

here is how i did in react js

```
  if (
  otCore.internalState &&
  otCore.internalState.subscribers &&
  otCore.internalState.subscribers.camera
) {
  let streams = otCore.internalState.subscribers.camera;
  let key = Object.keys(streams)[0];
  let object = streams[key];
  if (object) {
    let imgData = object.getImgData();

    let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.style =
      "display: flex;justify-content: center;flex-direction: column;justify-items: center;align-items: center; min-height: -webkit-fill-available;";

    let img = document.createElement("img");
    img.setAttribute("src", "data:image/png;base64," + imgData);
    img.setAttribute("height", "60%");
    img.setAttribute("width", "70%");

    var imgWin = window.open("", "", "postwindow");
    imgWin.document.write("<title>DstTok:Annotation</title>");
    imgWin.document.write("<body style='background:#666666'></body>");
    div.appendChild(img);
    imgWin.document.body.appendChild(div);
  }
}
```

}